# Simplifying a Boolean algebra expression

Tags: boolean-algebra

~ABC + ~BCD + ~A~BC~D + ABCD = ?

The solution book gives this answer:

~AC + CD

I arrived this one:

ACD

My question is if the method used to simplify can affect the result or if should it be equal?

Note: ~ stands for not ( ~A = Not A)

My steps:

~ABC + ~BCD + ~A~BC~D + ABCD =

=CD(~B+AB) + ~AC(B+~B~D)=

=CD(~B+A) + ~AC(B+~D)=

=~BCD + ACD + ~ABC + ~AC~D=

=C(~BD + AD + ~AB + ~A~D)=

=C[D(~B + A + ~AB + ~A~D)]=

=C[D(~B + A + B + ~A~D)]=

=C[D(A + ~A~D)]=

=C[D(A + ~D)]=

=CDA + CD~D=

=ACD

Answer (score 2):

It's possible to get an answer that looks different, but it should always be logically equivalent, no matter what route you take.

Unfortunately, your answer is not equivalent to the one provided by the book: If $A$ is False, and $C$ is True, then your expression is False, but the one from the book is True.

Try this: take the second and third term: $B'CD$ and $A'B'CD'$. Notice that they both have $B'C$ in common, so that definitely has to be true in order for one of those terms to be true. However, for the first term to be true, you also need $D$, while for the second you need $A'D'$, and so for one of those to hold you either need $D$ or $A'$ (because you already have $D'$ if not $D$). So, these two terms can be simplified to $B'CD$ and $A'B'C$

Formally:

$B'CD+A'B'CD'= B'C(D + A'D')= B'C(D+A')(D+D')=B'C(D+A')1=B'C(D+A')=B'CD+B'CA'$

Comment: Could you say me where is my mistake in the resolution?

Comment: @WilsonLima If you show me the steps you got to your answer, yes.

Comment: Just edited my question. It have the steps. thanks for your help!

Comment: @WilsonLima Your mistake is on line 6 when you pull out the D ...~A~D does not contain a D, so that should stay outside the parentheses

Comment: @WilsonLima ... so instead you get C(D(~B+A+B)+~A~D)=C(D(1)+~A~D)=C(D+~A~D)=C(D+~A)=CD+~AC ... looks like the book is right! :)

Comment: ahahaha seems true. I didnt pay attention to that. Really thanks alot! I was like 2 hours trying to figure out my mistake!

Comment: @WilsonLima easy to make mistakes with this stuff .. :) glad I could help